# 500 (Internal Server Error) in post request(.net core 2.0)

Tags: .net, .net-core

> My error message and code is like below. service.ts method is called but http call does
>   not reach controller class. I have enabled cors also but result was
>   still same.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa5p5.png)

Service.ts

```
saveEmployee(employee : User) {
        return this._http.post(this.myAppUrl + 'api/RoadSign/RegisterUser', employee).map((response: Response) => response.json()).catch(this.errorHandler)
}
```

Controller.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public class RoadSignController : Controller
{


   [HttpPost]
   [Route("RegisterUser")]
   public int Create([FromBody] User employee)
   {
       _repoWrapper.userRepo.Create(employee);
       return 1;
   }
```

Comment: try changing it to something like `public int Create() => 4;` just to test if it is a phrasing issue

Comment: There should be the error message in the HTTP response, you can check it in the Network tab of your browser. If there is no error, then you need to enable error reporting.

Comment: `_repoWrapper.userRepo.Create(employee);` I'm having the feeling that you didn't inject the `_repoWrapper` correctly int to the controller or you didn't registered its Interface and Implementation (Concrete Class) in to `IServiceCollection`.

Comment: Please don't post any text or code as an image. Edit your question to omit the image because it's not searchable, not visible within the question and prone to disappear at some point in the future, rendering the question incomplete.